# Updating a Running Service with another Version? [C#]

Tags: c#

I need to find a reliable way to update a running Windows Service (Service.exe).
The service is run under the LocalSystem account whereas the logged-in user is in a non-admin User account.

My current solution would be as follows:
- The Service.exe checks for updates (files) regularily
- When an update it found it starts another service (Launcher.exe) that would stop the Service.exe, copy over the files, restart Service.exe, then stop itself

After doing some online-reading and from some of my previous forum posts I beleive this would be the appropriate solution - but before I go ahead I wanted to check with all the guru's and see if I am forgetting something important or if there is a better way.

I did read-up on some method of self-updating (loading & unloading assemblies, etc...) but it just seemed very unsure and I need this to be as robust as possible - if it fails it means someone needs to manually intervene.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The download / stop / apply changes / restart procedure is a fairly common and robust one. I definitely *wouldn't* try to get into the business of doing it without restarting. It may well be possible in many cases, but it's going to be a *lot* harder to get right.

Don't forget to make sure you can update the updater, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bootstrapper service as well.

Basically it's a lightweight service that you install, it watches a directory for dll's that match a certain interface.

Anything that matches, it loads up and runs as a service inside of itself.

Have it load two dlls to start.  One is your service, the other is your update service.

Since there is virtually no code in the bootstrapper it *shouldn't* need to be updated.

But your updater will be able to update itself, and the service dll periodically.

How your updater works is up to you.  We found that having a publish location on our network, and just watching the folder for updates, additions and delete's and synching the local dll folder was sufficient, but you could have it monitor a config file that point to dlls all over if that is what is needed (had to do that for one worldwide update system).

It's a bit tricky to get it all setup and working correctly.  But once it is, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite the right solution, however somebody (usually the main service) needs to carry code to update the launcher.

The launcher cannot do itself for what should be obvious reasons.

I do a double launcher (launcher spawns second service that updates both) to simplify update checks.

BTW even in the UNIX world we apply the same basic steps only we overwrite the running binary while the service is still running. In the Windows world you can do the same thing by renaming all files you are about to overwrite out of the way first.